# Creating a JavaScript Array with Multiple Elements and nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to assign multiple elements and nested arrays to represent several mp3 files.  Each array item will be assigned several unique elements

```
const sermon = {
    id: "",
    topic: "",
    book: "",
    bookPart: "",
    path: "",
    file: "",
    fileType: "",
    sermonName: function() { 
        return (this.book + " " + this.bookPart).toUpperCase(); 
    }
};
```

So basically I would like

```
sermon[0] = { id: "01" topic: "New Testament", book: "Hebrews", bookPart: "Part 1", path: "sermons/" + sermon.book, file: "hebrews_part1.mp3", fileType: "mp3", sermonName: "HEBREWS PART 1"
```

The "id, book, topic" would be the same for each "sermon.bookPart, sermon.file".  For each book the "id, book, and topic" would change (as expected)

It would write to the following:

```
<h3 id="demo"></h3>
<p id="topic"></p>
<p id="book"></p>
<p id="file"></p>
<p id="path"></p>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sermon.sermonName();
document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML = sermon.topic;
document.getElementById("book").innerHTML = sermon.book;
document.getElementById("file").innerHTML = sermon.file;
document.getElementById("path").innerHTML = sermon.path;
```

I've tried to manually populate and assign arrays, but got stuck trying to do 3 nested for loops to  add "Part 1,2,3" in with the book[] arrays

```
let x = "";
const sermon = {
    topic: "New Testament",
    path: "sermons/",
    book: [
        { name: "Hebrews", files: ["hebrews_part1.mp3", "hebrews_part2.mp3", "hebrews_part3.mp3"] },
        { name: "1Corinthians", files: ["1cor_part1.mp3", "1cor_part2.mp3", "1cor_part3.mp3"] }
    ]
};

for (let i in sermon.book) {
    x += "<h3>" + sermon.book[i].name + "</h3>";
    for (let j in sermon.book[i].files) {
        x += "<a href=" + sermon.path + sermon.book[i].name + "/" + sermon.book[i].files[j] + ">" + sermon.book[i].files[j] + "</a><br>";
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to convert the `sermon` object to another array.

```
const sermons =
[
    topic: "New Testament",
    path: "sermons/",
    book: [
        { name: "Hebrews", files: ["hebrews_part1.mp3", "hebrews_part2.mp3", "hebrews_part3.mp3"] },
        { name: "1Corinthians", files: ["1cor_part1.mp3", "1cor_part2.mp3", "1cor_part3.mp3"] }
    ], 
... // add more sermons here
]
};
```

you can then iterate over the sermons using another for loop. Unfortunately, this is just a result of the structure. What you can do is then create a new variable to reference the current level of iteration, i.e. `sermons` is the top level object, but each `sermon` is just another name for `sermons[h]`, `sermon.book[i]` becomes `book`, etc., that way it's a little easier to visualize what you're using.

```
for (let h in sermons) {
    let sermon = sermons[h];
    for (let i in sermon.book) {
        let book = sermon.book[i];
        x += "<h3>" + book.name + "</h3>";
        for (let j in book.files) {
            x += "<a href=" + sermon.path + book.name + "/" + book.files[j] + ">" + book.files[j] + "</a><br>";
        }
    }
}
```